# need help setting up smtp from localhost

Tags: php, smtp

I'm running XP Pro, and I have a XAMPP setup.  I'm learning Zend Framework, and I'm trying to use Zend_Mail.  I guess I need to setup or configure my SMTP on my machine for this to work?

Can anyone tell me how to do this and most importantly how to test this to know if it's working (maybe an easier way than zend_mail because I'm a newbie there too and I may be doing other things wrong there).

So in short, I just want to set up SMTP and mail from localhost just to be sure things are set up correctly.

PS: so far, I have turned on (installed) the IIS from the windows components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll likely be easier to use an external SMTP server such as the one provided by your ISP.

See the [Zend Framework Manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.sending.html) for instructions on using the smtp transport.

Comment: Yes, I've been reading the horrible manual for days...

Comment: I'm going to mark your answer correct as a combination of my answer and your answer has led me to a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I found this and it got me up and running and even had a simple test:
http://roshanbh.com.np/2007/12/sending-e-mail-from-localhost-in-php-in-windows-environment.html

Turns out that the Windows component IIS seems unneeded here.  I had to disable it for my apache server to connect.